# How to pass a specific value to each thread of a pool in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

Disclaimer: I'm terrible at coding and not a native speaker!

In the following piece of code, when order = 4, check method gets called as and when a new cCycle is generated. The `puts currCycle` in check method prints 0 1 2 4 9 3 6 13 10 5 11 7 15 but when I print the same in getData method of a thread, it prints 1 1 3 3 9 9 13 13 5 11 7 7 15. I'm not completely sure why this is happening.

I need each thread to perform some operations on the `currCycle` value that was passed to it.

I have tried to clone/dup the currCycle object so that each thread works on one specific value rather than multiple threads operating on the same value and skipping few. (I'm guessing this has something to do with shared memory or race condition)

```
require 'thread/pool'

$cycle = ""
$order = 4

def debruijn($order)
  # ....
  loop {
    #....
    # cCycle values in each iteration {0, 0001, 0011, 01, 0111, 1}
    check(cCycle)
    #....
  }
  # ....
end

def check(cCycle)
  $cycle = $cycle + cCycle # append cCycle to left over subsequence from previous iteration
  pool = Thread.pool(1,8)
  while $cycle.length >= $order do
    # Get first n (=order) bits from cycle
    currCycle = $cycle[0...$order].to_i(2).to_s # binary string to integer string 
    # pop the first char from cycle
    $cycle = $cycle[1..-1]
    puts currCycle
    pool.process {
      getData(currCycle)
    }
  end
  while !pool.done? do
    sleep(2)
  end
  pool.shutdown
end

def getData(currCycle)
  puts currCycle
  # perform operations on currCycle
end
# ....
```

I'm working on a personal research project that generates a [De Bruijn Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). For example, debruijn(order=4) would produce *0000100110101111*. This sequence contains all possible 4 bit subsequences from *0000* to *1111* if you traverse from left to right 4 bits at a time and append bits from the beginning when you reach the end (a cyclic sequence). {0000, 0001, 0010, ...., 1111, 1110, 1100, 1000}

The algorithm that generates this sequence, in each iteration, generates a string (cCycle) either of length 1, 2 or 4 like *1*, *10* or *1011*. Since I'm working with higher orders (order=128+, sequenceLength = 2**order), saving the entire sequence is impractical and unnecessary.

Comment: If you're using threads, the **absolute last thing you want involved is global variables**. In Ruby these are prefixed with `$` and can cause considerable problems in normal code, but those problems are magnified with threads. You also do not want, under any circumstances, a global variable being specified as a method argument. It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Why do you need threads in the first place? Are you CPU-bound? If so, under normal Ruby that won't help one bit. You need to use a Ruby without a GVL to effectively utilize more than one thread, as in TruffleRuby or JRuby. Remember with threads, shared mutable data of *any kind* is extremely problematic and requires Mutex locks to properly synchronize.

Comment: My need basically is to work with billions of >128 bit binary strings that get transformed heavily in getData method and also interact with postgres databases. Since De Bruijn algorithm does generate 128 strings at a time, I'd like to concurrently run those transformations. I'm not married to threads per se. That's where I started. I'm open to suggestions. 

Regarding your comment about global variable as a method argument, my actual code does not do that. I just edited that code on the fly for this question here. No one will read my actual code, ever. But, thanks.

Comment: I'm currently running this code on my laptop with quad core processor. Might eventually run it on a rack server. As I write this comment and after reading your comments, I think multiple processes are better choice than multiple threads in this case. One concurrent process has no need to interact with others nor do they have any shared memory requirement here. I'll look into that.

Comment: A) Never underestimate the power of `xargs`, especially the `--max-procs` option to run things in parallel. B) Consider JRuby if you're looking into threads as it actually gives you multiple threads running concurrently. C) While I'm generally a big fan of Ruby for a lot of things, CPU-bound workloads is not one. You may want to look at doing this in a compiled language (C, C++, even Rust) to see how performance compares. You may find it's 40x faster than Ruby.

Comment: For A, B, I will definitely look into them. Believe it or not, my first version of this code is in C++. I switched to ruby because of the libraries. When I said transformations in getData, they rely heavily on multiple external libraries (OpenSSL, PostgreSQL etc...). I literally scratched my skull off trying to get them to work together and eventually switched to Ruby (as I have reasonable experience with it). I will reconsider C++ or probably checkout Julia and it's libraries. Thank you for taking the time. Appreciate it.